# Should I use filesystem or database to store my data in my music recognition app?

Tags: c++, database, filesystems, gracenote

I have created a music recognition app.
I would like to display previously identified songs.
Where should I store those data about the songs? in database or filesystem?
While one or the other?
data= album name , track name, artist, cover image, genre, youtube link.

Comment: You need more detail than just "data" to make that decision.

Comment: data= album name , track name, artist, cover image, genre, youtube link.

Comment: How are you going to interact with the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to display a single source of non-relational data, then a file is probably the easiest solution.

Once you need relationships between entities, not using a database would be reinventing the wheel.

So if you want a plain list of the data you have, use a file.

If you want an album entity with related track entities and a user entity where each user references a certain track from a certain album, use a database.